# I evoke my computer's printer from my web page but it prints a blank page

Tags: vb.net, printing

m inexperienced at web programming, learning as I go.  In my vb.net application I have created a printable web page.  Now I want to make it easier for users by automatically invoking their printer.  I believe that control + p will invoke a printer in most browsers, so I am trying that.  (I realize it is not an elegant solution and am open to something better.)  But the problem I am having is that I can evoke the printer dialog, however it prints an empty page with only the standard header and footer.  I thought maybe the printer was coming up before the page was ready, so I tried putting in a time delay, but the delay seems to occur before the page renders on the page, rather than after the page is rendered and before the printer dialog shows.  I am still getting empty pages.  What should I do?

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ScaleID = Request.QueryString.ToString
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmdScale As New SqlCommand("Select * from ScalesView where [Scale ID] = @ScaleID", myConnection)
        Dim daScale As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dsScale As New Data.DataSet
        Dim dtScale As New Data.DataTable
        myConnection.Open()
        cmdScale.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScaleID", ScaleID)
        daScale.SelectCommand = cmdScale
        cmdScale.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dsScale.Clear()
        daScale.Fill(dsScale, "ScalesView")
        dtScale = dsScale.Tables(0)

        lblName.Text = dtScale.Rows(0)("Client Name")
        lblRater.Text = dtScale.Rows(0)("Rater Name")
        lblBehavior.Text = dtScale.Rows(0)("Behavior Name")
        lblDate.Text = dtScale.Rows(0)("Date")
        lblSetting.Text = dtScale.Rows(0)("Setting Name")
                    lblA9.Text = dtScale.Rows(0)("Item 9")
                    lblD9.Text = Description(lblA9.Text)
        'more code to display data here
    End Using
    txtTotSensory.Text = (CInt(lblA1.Text) + CInt(lblA5.Text) + CInt(lblA9.Text) + CInt(lblA13.Text)).ToString
    txtTotEscape.Text = (CInt(lblA2.Text) + CInt(lblA6.Text) + CInt(lblA10.Text) + CInt(lblA14.Text)).ToString
    txtTotAttention.Text = (CInt(lblA3.Text) + CInt(lblA7.Text) + CInt(lblA11.Text) + CInt(lblA15.Text)).ToString
    txtTotTangible.Text = (CInt(lblA4.Text) + CInt(lblA8.Text) + CInt(lblA12.Text) + CInt(lblA16.Text)).ToString
    'more data manipulation here
    sortIt()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("^(p)")
End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to print a web page from *server-side code*?  Is there a particular reason for that?  Normally one would just call `window.print()` in JavaScript.  Also, why are you sleeping the thread for 10 seconds?  That's just going to make the browser wait for the page for no real reason.

Comment: @JanGreve: There's no interpolated string here.  That's a parameterized SQL query.  The parameter is added 5 lines later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a *very good reason* for going about things this way, it sounds like you're missing a fundamental part of web development.  Namely, the separation of server-side and client-side code/functionality.

If the page should be printed from the browser, that's *client-side*.  Printing client-side is a simple JavaScript call:

```
window.print();
```

You basically *can't* invoke the client's printer from server-side code.  (Imagine an internet where any server you visit could interact with your computer's hardware.)  You *can* print to the *server's* printer (not sure why anybody would want to), but in that case you'd need something to print.  And rendering the page in-memory on the server just to print it seems like overkill.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the web page can be formatted differently for printing by using a CSS @media query.

Comment: Thanks.  That is helpful.  I have written JavaScript before but not in the current context (vb.net, Visual Studio 2008) so I don't even know where it put it--obviously not in the code behind.  I'm going to have to do some research to figure out how to use your advice.  My grasp of client side vs. server side is hazy.  It seems like a clear enough concept, but when it gets down to the actual facts of using it, it's not always clear to me.

Comment: @Andrew, my calling this a printable page is not quite accurate.  It really is a summary of a scale.  When the user fills out the scale, it will appear to them to be spread over 4 pages.  The "printable" page summarizes everything in a single page so they can print it for their records.  I considered using CSS, but since I want to print only this singe page summary and no other pages, it seemed simpler just to set up the page the way I wanted it.

Comment: @David  My previous comment meant for you David but I neglected to put your name in the comment

Comment: @LouAtMonaco: Well, I don't really know how your user experience is designed, but the fact remains that in a web application if you want the user to print something then that would be done client-side.  Using CSS `@media` directives for a printable version of the page could be *drastically* different than what's seen on the screen, there's no rule saying the styling has to match perfectly.  Or you could perhaps have a "summary" page that the user sees when clicking a link, and *that* page is what gets printed.

Comment: Woo Hoo!  That worked.  I just stuck a little JavaScript in the markup view of the designer page.  So easy.  And knowing how to use JavaScript in this context is going to help me with another problem.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @LouAtMonaco You could even have the summary present on all four pages, but hidden for screen (via `@media screen....`) so that the summary can be printed from any of the four pages. Of course, it depends on the workflow of the end users as to how you actually implement it - I suggest asking them how they'd like it to go.